# Which easy to use authentication algorithm for embedded devices do you know?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, embedded

I've an embedded device (E) with limited code size. It communicates with host processor (H) using UART (USB, serial, ..). I need to implement an easy authentication of the host processor to unlock function is my embedded device.

The important issue is that USB/serial/UART can be sniffed, so the channel is not secure.

The usage should be the following:
during manufacturing we generate a pair of keys Ke and Kh.
E stores Ke
E generates N random bytes R, encrypts R into secret S with key Ke and sends to H
H should enrypt S using Kh to reveal R
H sends R to E and E unlocks some functionality

So,

```
S = u(R, Ke)
R = v(S, Kh)
```

Where `u()` and `v()` are some crypto function (it might be that `u = v`, but `u` MUST be easy to implement in embedded device taking samll code space).

It should be even better to find an alog that allows to have many Kh for same Ke to give them to different users. But this is optional.

As mentioned above, the channel is not secure, so we do not want an evil sitting on the USB (with an USB sniffer) to reveal Ke or Kh (or the way to generate R from S) just from R and S.

So, XOR will not work ;)

Please propose something

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out your threat model.  Can the host be compromised and reveal its secret?  Can the same happen to the device?  How many times do you need to do this between a pair, and do you need to handle more than one pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can your device give the processor some nonce and verify answer as encrypted nonce using some lightweight encryption algorithm (e.g. RC5) ? This can also help you to establish a secure channel between your device and a processor. For example, answer can be `RC5_CBC( CONCAT(key_for_secure_channel, nonce) )`. Note: nonce must be written at the end, so new key integrity will be verified by them.

Comment: RC5 seems to be lightweight enough to be implemented in an embedded device. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at CHAP, one of the authentication protocols supported by PPP.
[Check out Wikipedia's page about CHAP.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol)

Comment: CHAP seems to use MD5, which is quite big to implement. I would like something "cheaper" in terms of code size.

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you need to do this and are K_h and K_e unique per pair?  The simplest way to do this would be to generate a random, pre-shared secret on both the device and the host (during manufacturing) and then use this as a one-time pad.

The basic idea of a one-time pad is the you take your message and XOR is with a secret.  As long as your secret is as long as your message and you only do this once, then you're fine.  Someone sniffing on your channel shouldn't be able to figure out what the message is because they also don't know what the secret is.  Of course, when you send the decrypted reply, someone sniffing on the channel will be able to decrypt everything.